# Trying to resolve type error to convert integer into an indices value

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ive been trying to store the newly created users password into its designated username for my login system project however, type error keeps occuring and im not to sure how to change my password value into an integer or resolve the problem. Thank you for helping

```
user = []
status = ""

status = input("Have You Registered With Our System? y/n")

username = input("Choose A Username: ")

if username in user:
        print("Username is already in use")
else:
        createPassword = input("Create Your Password: ")
        user[username] = createPassword
        print("\n User Has Been Created \n")


        login = input(" Enter login name: ")
password = input( " Enter Password: ")

if login in user and user[login] == password:
        print("\n Successfully loged in\n")
        #with open("user.txt", "w") as f:
        f = open("user.txt", "a")
        #print(f.mode)
        #f.close()
        f.write(login)
        f.write(" ")
        f.write(password)
        f.write(" ")
        f.close()

else:
        print("\n User Does Not Exist or Wrong Features")
```

Comment: Could you post the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are hitting a `TypeError` is because `lists` are indexed with integer values, rather than strings.

I think a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) might be a bit more helpful here, as you can store `strings`, `ints`, even `tuples` as keys (but not `lists`, `sets`, or `dicts`):

```py
users = {}

username = 'testuser'
password = '1234knaoiva'

if username in users:
    if password != users[username]:
        raise ValueError("Invalid Password")
    else:
        print("Login successful")

else:
    users[username] = password
    print("Welcome, new user!")
```

This has a few advantages. First, tests for membership in a `dict` are *much* faster for large amounts of data, and doesn't change as the size of the dictionary grows. Whereas testing a `list` for membership grows the more values (or in your case, users) it contains

To show how this works in your case:

```py
users = {} # Users is an empty dictionary

username = input("What's your username? ") # testuser

username in users
# False
# Fails membership test

users[username] = input("What's your password? ") # testpass
users

# {'testuser': 'testpass'}

users[username]
# testpass
```

To show the performance difference over membership tests (worst case) on small versus large groups of data:

### 100 Elements, Worst Case

```py
# List
python -m timeit -s 'd = [i for i in range(100)]' '999999 in d'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.801 usec per loop 

# Dict
-m timeit -s 'd = {i: None for i in range(100)}' '999999 in d'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0262 usec per loop
```

### 1000000 Elements, Worst Case

```py
# List
-m timeit -s 'd = [i for i in range(1000000)]' '999999 in d'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 8.34 msec per loop

# Dict
-m timeit -s 'd = {i: None for i in range(1000000)}' '999999 in d'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0343 usec per loop
```

For smaller amounts of data you don't see too much of a difference (on a modern processor), though even at only 100 elements, `dict` is faster by an order of magnitude. For larger amounts, the difference is astronomical

Comment: Thank you so much it makes more sense to me know ur a life saver my friend Thank you honestly :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `username`'s type is 'str' and not int, which you can't convert to int unless the username is all 0's and 1's.

I recommend using a dictionary for holding usernames and passwords:

```
user = {}

# in creating password:
    createPassword = input("Create Your Password: ")
    user[username] = createPassword // This works because dictionary keys can be str
    print("\n User Has Been Created \n")
```

Then to check if a username is inside of the dictionary you use `if name in user.keys():`